# db2 replace fails with SQLCODE=-171

Tags: sql, db2

We have a select statement with the following:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(EMAIL, x'00', ''), '\n', '') AS EMAIL FROM tabname
```

This fails with SQLCODE=-171 because EMAIL is empty.
What is the most efficient way to replace EMAIL only if EMAIL has content?
EMAIL is defined as a varchar. The actual select is pulling multiple columns and doing a replace on most.

Comment: Are you sure the replace is the issue?  I don't have an issue with the replace function over either an empty string or a NULL value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you do it?

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(ifnull(EMAIL, ''), x'00', ''), '\n', '') AS EMAIL FROM tabname
```

Comment: That was really close. I changed it to nullif. When I used ifnull I receive `Code: -171, SQL State: 42815]  THE DATA TYPE, LENGTH, OR VALUE OF ARGUMENT 1 OF SYSIBM.REPLACE IS INVALID.` . When I use nullif the replace works.